# No user on brand new OS X installation

Tags: macos, mac, installation, macbook-pro, osx-mavericks

I just opened a new **Macbook Pro** out of the box and, after going through the initial setup (language, timezone, name, etc.), I see the login screen without my username. I tried typing in my username (manually) and password but nothing happens. The only option is to click the back button which then shows a blank alias picture with the word **Other** underneath it

If I reboot the computer pressing `Command+S`and then do `ls /Users` to see the users on the system it only has `.localized` and `Shared` directories.

How do I correct this so I can have an initial user account?

Comment: Try `rm /var/db/.AppleSetupDone` in Single User Mode to force the initial setup to run again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, reboot and hold `Command+S` while it's booting to enter single user mode. When the command line comes up, run the following two commands:

```
mount -uw /
rm /var/db/.AppleSetupDone
```

Then reboot the usual way or, if you want to be fancy, use the command line by typing `shutdown -r now`

After that, I went through the setup the exact same way as before but this time it actually ended with my user logging in.